# How can I make an Image.fillAmount behave like a unity.Slider?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an Image acting as an audio progress indicator, and the code so far is -

```
 var results = new double[1] { 0.0 };
 audioEngine.AE_get_active_theme_index(AEplayer.player.Handle, results);
 float current_time = (float)results[0];
 current_time += Time.deltaTime;
 cooldown.fillAmount = current_time;
```

Im working with a third-party audio-engine that outputs (current_time) the current time elapsed in the playing song/theme. When I run this, the image fills up from 0-100 in under 1sec.

I tried the same function on a unity.Slider and thats working almost perfectly.

Comment: Do you want the input functionality that a `Slider` provides or just the "percentage along a range" functionality?

Comment: I think I would want the funtionality of a Slider. I need it to behave just like a normal audio progress indicator, found in a regular mediaplayer like vlc/itunes/spotify etc.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just use a `Slider`, then?  In most cases, it's easier to get a slider's visuals to do what you want rather than get an `Image` to handle input the way a `Slider` does.

Comment: The progress bar is a curved red/orange line, and Im not sure how to implement the image onto the Slider

Comment: Since I have a function called 'theme.length' that outputs the current theme's length in seconds, cant I do something like - cooldown.fillAmount = current_time /*+ theme.Length ?

Comment: Yea, that'll get the percentage properly set for the `fillAmount`, you'll then just need to write your own input logic.

Comment: I'm using a Slider now instead, but the fillamount is not working -         `audioSlider.direction = Slider.Direction.LeftToRight;
        audioSlider.minValue = 1;
        audioSlider.maxValue = lengd;`

update()
        `current_time += Time.deltaTime;`
        audioSlider.value = current_time;